# How to setup a snakemake rule whose target files are determined by file content?

Tags: python, bash, workflow, bioinformatics, snakemake

I would like to split a sam file into multiple sam files according to the barcode info. And the query barcode info are list in another file.

```sh
$ cat barcode.list
ATGCATGC
TTTTAAAA
GGGGCCCC
CGCGATGA
AAGGTTCC
....
```

> A simple bash script below can achieve the goal.

```sh
barcode_list=./A_barcode.csv
input_bam=./A_input.bam
splited_dir=./splited_sam/A
filtered_dir="./filterd_sam/A"

mkdir -p ${splited_dir} ${splited_dir}
header=$(samtools view -H ${input_bam})
samtools view {input.bam} | LC_ALL=C fgrep -f <(cat ${barcode_list}) | awk -v header="${header}" -v outdir="${splited_dir}" '{barcode=substr($0,index($0, "\tCB:Z:")+6,18);if (!header_printed[barcode]++) {print $0 >> outdir"/"barcode".sam"}}'
for sam in ${output_dir};do samtools view -q 30 -m 1 ${sam} -O bam -o ${filtered_dir}/$(basename ${sam} "sam")"bam";done
```

> **Note:** Only barcodes that are in both `barcode_list` file and `input_bam` file  will be recorded into a new file.

But I want to rewrite the script into sankemake pipeline for better scaling up. The solution that I tried is shown below.

**I don't known how to assign input file name in the final step of all the rules**, `rule all` in this example. Because they are determined by both `input_bam` and `input_barcode` file. Meanwhile, without the knowledge of `splited_sam` filename, I can't go though the next step either.

```
SAMPLES = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
# BARCODE = ???

rule all:
  input:
    splited_sam_dir = expand("splited_sam/{sample}", sample=SAMPLES)

rule split_sam:
  input:
    bar = "{sample}_barcode.csv",
    bam = "{sample}_input.bam"
  output:
    splited_sam_dir = "splited_sam/{sample}"
  shell:
    """
    header=$(samtools view -H {input.bam})
    samtools view {input.bam} | LC_ALL=C fgrep -f <(cat {input.bar}) | awk -v header="$header" -v outdir="{output.splited_sam_dir}" '{{barcode=substr($0,index($0, "\tCB:Z:")+6,18);if (!header_printed[barcode]++) {{print $0 >> outdir"/"barcode".sam"}}}}
    """
rule filter_sam:
  # ??? don't know the input file name...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define "split_sam" as a checkpoint rule, see [the doc on checkpoints](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#data-dependent-conditional-execution).
The DAG will be recalculated for all rules that depend on the output of this rule once the checkpoint rule is executed.